# list filter: for each word matched, increment by 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/yshcR/2/

you can type into the input box any of the words you see in the list, when a full word is typed that matches a word in the list, it will hide all list-items that do not contain any of the words that are typed into the input. You can type multiple words, and it will match multiple `li`'s. I appended a span: `.keywordcount` to the end of each `li`. I'm trying to get each `.keywordcount` span to increase or decrease by the number of matched words in that `li`. So if I typed "canada denmark" into the input box, every `li` that contains those 2 words should have their `.keywordcount` span incremented to "2". If an `li` only contained 1 of those words, then it's `.keywordcount` would be "1".

I've tried everything I can but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/yshcR/4/